# How I use keyPressed event using GameCanvas in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

Well, I have a problem that I can't solve and tried it in many ways, but, with no success. I want to press a button and if it stay down, the bullet can't fire.

So I tried this, first:

```
public void checkInput() {
    int iKeyPressed;

    iKeyPressed = this.getKeyStates();

    if((iKeyPressed & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) {
        this.player.moveLeft();
    }
    else if((iKeyPressed & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) {
        this.player.moveRight();
    }

    if((iKeyPressed & FIRE_PRESSED) != 0 && this.bKeyReleased) {
        Bullet bullet;
        int x;
        int y;

        bullet = new Bullet(loadImage("bullet.png"), 4, 22, 1, (this.player.getVel()*2)*(-1));
        x = (this.player.getX()+(this.player.getWidth()/2))-(bullet.getWidth()/2);
        y = this.player.getY();
        bullet.setPosition(x, y);
        this.lstBullets.addElement(bullet);
        //this.bKeyReleased = false;
    }
}
```

And I call this method in my main loop. This works, but if the key stay down, the bullets still coming out. When I try to override the keyPressed method, it doesn't work, because I don't know how to call this method. If I try to call it directly in my main loop it doesn't work, so, how could I can make it works?

Anyone can show me how I call this method to works correctly?

Comment: what is the value of parameter you pass to [constructor of your GameCanvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/GameCanvas.html#GameCanvas(boolean))? from your description it feels like you set it `true` - this would suppress keyPressed features for game keys. Try to set this parameter `false` and re-test the code that you tried with keyPressed/Released

Answer (score 1):

getKeyStates() doesn't report events per se.  It will return true on a key if it is held down OR was down at some point between the current call to getKeyStates and the last call to it.  You will have to override the [keyReleased](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#keyReleased%28int%29) method to take action when the user lets the key up instead of when they push it down.